# Sprite Kit game coordination confuse

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I'm making a game with SpriteKit on Swift and I need to draw text label on top left screen.

My game info (iPhone 6 Landscape)

```
let viewSize = view.frame.size // 667x375
let sceneSize = scene!.frame.size // 1024x768

self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

Then I'm get top left coords by (x: minX, y: maxY)

```
convertPointFromView(CGPointMake(view.frame.minX, view.frame.maxY))
```

Return is (x: -512, y: **-287**). It should be (x: -512, y: **287**) I'm get top left by touch location (I'm thinking cause from anchorPoint at center, Right ?)

Then, I try to use this (x: minX, y: minY)

```
convertPointFromView(CGPointMake(view.frame.minX, view.frame.minY))
```

Now, my text label presented on top left screen.

Why top left is not (x: minX, y: maxY) ? explained to me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UIView coordinates, y = 0 at the top of the screen, and y increases as you go down. In SpriteKit coordinates, y increases as you go up.